# Kotlin: 'public' property exposes its 'local' type argument <no name provided>

Tags: java, kotlin, lambda

```
interface A {
    fun f() : String
}

val B = { attr : String ->
    object : A {
        override fun f() = attr
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error at the definition of `B`:

```
'public' property exposes its 'local' type argument <no name provided>
```

What is the cause of this error?

Answer (score 3):

You are returning an anonymous singleton object, and kotlin is not able to figure out the type for which no name is provided. You can specify the type of `B` explicitly to fix this issue

```
val B: (String) -> A = { attr: String ->
    object : A {
        override fun f() = attr
    }
}
```